# Spotify Auth API Invalid Client: Invalid Redirect URI

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, spotify

I access Spotify API on my local machine without any problem. I supply to spotify auth request my local address as redirect_uri parameter(http://localhost:8080) and I also added this URI in the Spotify Developer Console to the whitelist.

But when I deploy my app to AWS I have a url like this: http://myapp-env.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

So I added this url to whitelist on Spotify Developer Console too and sending this url to Spotify authorization request as redirect_uri parameter. But this time spotify returns *'Invalid Client: Invalid Redirect URI'* error.

Is there something wrong with the AWS url?

EDIT: I discovered that when you pass a uri that is whitelisted in the Spotify Developer Console, if the hostname of the machine making the request does not match the host of the uri, spotify returns invalid_redirect_uri.

So maybe it's because AWS has load balancing and the hostname of the machine is different than the url above. Is there any way to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It's because I forgot to change the redirect uri of the [https://accounts.spotify.com/api/authorize request](https://accounts.spotify.com/api/authorize%C2%A0request) and sent different (although valid) redirect uri in https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token request. The two must match.